# Strategies for reverse engineering project that uses Guice?

Tags: java, netbeans, dependency-injection, reverse-engineering, guice

I have tried to understand dependency injection and not quite gotten it, except I have managed to pick up the understanding that it makes it hard to understand somebody else's code. :'(

Anyway, I'm not sure how to briefly describe my problem but I will try.  I am currently the sole coder working on a Java project that's been worked on by dozens of loners over about six years.  It makes heavy use of Google's Guice library.  I'm supposed to take some existing code and implement it differently; specifically, use the existing methods for password authentication and, instead of applying it to each JMenuItem in a JMenu, apply it to the whole JMenu, so that if the wrong password or no password is entered, all JMenuItems are disabled.  This doesn't happen if the password is wrong, leading me to believe the problem is in the if statement, which is a long string of dependencies in itself:
`if (!ViewScanApp.getApplication().getHistoryManager().isAuthenticated())`

I trace my way back through this, to find that the `HistoryManager` class is an interface, and there my path seems to die; there's no code there, and it doesn't make a reference to any other class.  I have found the end of the path through random exploration of the 100-odd classes in the project, but I can't quite seem to connect them.  I cannot find where the first class I can find on the other end of this stack, `AccessManagerImpl`, gets called.

I could use an explanation of dependency injection that might be applicable to this situation.  Thank you so much!

Comment: "Dependency Injection" is just like "new" except it happens by magic instead of you having to type "new"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there's no `@ImplementedBy` annotation on the `HistoryManager` interface, you'll need to examine the Guice `Module` that is responsible for binding this type.

In Eclipse, there is a command to look for occurrences of a class. I'll bet that Netbeans has something similar. Use it to look for occurrences of `HistoryManager`. At least one of these should occur in a class that implements `com.google.inject.Module` (or extends `AbstractModule`). You'll likely see something like

```
protected void configure() {
  …
  bind(HistoryManager.class).to(HistoryManagerImpl.class);
  …
}
```

Or, if you like quick-and-dirty empiricism, you can throw in a `println()`:

```
HistoryManager mgr = ViewScanApp.getApplication().getHistoryManager();
System.out.println("HistoryManager implementation: " + mgr.getClass());
if (!mgr.isAuthenticated())
   …
```

However you locate it, `HistoryManagerImpl` class is where you'll want to pick up the trail.

I haven't used it, but the [Guice graphing tool](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Grapher) might be helpful too.

Comment: The problem was solved by a deus ex machina: The original programmer.  The test statement you gave me yielded $proxy7, which I don't understand.  He then pointed me in the direction of the right class which dictates the bindings I couldn't see elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Fire up a debugger. It will walk you through the exact class that is implementing that interface (assuming you have the source code to it)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have an interface definition in Eclipse which is injected with Guice, instead of using F3 to go to the defintion which you would do if it was a class, then use Ctrl-T to choose among the implementations of that interface.

If you have more than one to choose from, then you need the module bindings printed out so you know which one to pick.  Unfortunately Eclipse doesn't understand injection yet.